# Can we use limit cause on 'show partitions tableName' in hive

Tags: hive

I have a hive table which has plenty of partitions, I want to get only 100 partitions when I execute `show partitions table name` command .

Answer (score 7):

Well, It's not possible to give clause with `SHOW PARTITIONS` query.

`SHOW PARTITIONS` lists all the existing partitions for a given base table. And those partitions are listed in alphabetical order.

But if you want to get the limited partitions, you can filter it based on the partitions like :

```
SHOW PARTITIONS table_name PARTITION(ds='2010-03-03');
```

These kind of queries will give you limited resultset.

For more information, you can refer the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowPartitions).

Comment: Can we do something like :
    ALTER TABLE  dim_plan DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(dimensional_partition_folder>'2016_04_30_20_00'  and dimensional_partition_folder <'2016_04_30_23_30');